# Parameter property declaration with open ended constructor arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is this possible ?

What i currently have and what works:

```
module app.typescriptdemoview {
    export class InitializeAutoComplete {
        constructor(... _inputIds: string[]) {
        // Initialize _inputIds as a member variable ..
        }
    }
}
```

What i would like to achieve:

```
module app.typescriptdemoview {
    export class InitializeAutoComplete {
        constructor(private ... _inputIds: string[]) { // Automatic member var. initialization
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but that would work if you removed the `...` part.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Adding a scope keyword in front of a constructor argument automatically initializes it as a class member variable without writing manually (for example) this._inputIds = _inputIds; I want to use that feature combined with the open ended constructor arguments (the ... syntax).

Comment: Ah, now I see what you're trying to do; sorry for being thick.  Doesn't seem to be possible, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't currently possible, so you are stuck with manually assigning it. The compiler would need a change to do this automatically.

```
class Test {
    private _args: string[];
    constructor (...args: string[]) {
        this._args = args;
    }
}
```